# How to sync an oracle database with online mysql database

Tags: mysql, synchronization

i have an application with oracle 10g express edition running in behind as database. but i want to auto synchronize all the data in that DB((oracle) to my online Mysql database whenever the internet is connected . can u please help with the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822954/import-data-to-mysql-from-oracle

Comment: You can use SQLyog for this. You can do this by installing ODBC driver for MySQL. There is an option to schedule on particular intervals.