# How way to copy oracle data to remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, database-administration

I need to copy oracle table data into remote mysql server.

I tried something and the list are below

1. The oracle data can export as .sql file and then remove the ddl statement and make 
   insert according to mysql syntax, this is not feasible since the process should be automated

2.
Making heterogeneous dblink, making dblink is done,dblink ping also successful but got error in select statement,ORA-28513: internal error in heterogeneous remote agent ORA-02063: preceding line from MYSQLLINK and heard that data loading via dblink is very slow

1. Or i should look into any ETL tool like penthao kettle

Any suggestion will be much appreciated

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822954/import-data-to-mysql-from-oracle/22936746#22936746 and i think SQLyog has an option to automate the process

Comment: that is sqlyog ultimate edition

Comment: Most of the tools which does this will be commercial versions.